# Trouble finding Wi-Fi Adapter

Tags: usb, wifi

I've followed this [guide](http://www.maketecheasier.com/setup-wifi-on-raspberry-pi/), wich explains to first check if my USB gets recognized by my raspberry by `lsusb` or `ifconfig`. I've tried both and this is what I get:
`ifconfig`
[image]

`lsusb`
[image]

So my Raspberry does recognize my wifi adapter as it should because it is a wifi adapter that is compatible for the Pi.

As I continue through the guide and start up my desktop and open WiFi config. There is no adapter at all. It should give me an adapter called `wlan0`. But it's just empty:

[image]
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this via shell:

```
sudo apt-get install wpasupplicant
```

Then edit the `/etc/network/interfaces` file

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

It should look something like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa.conf
```

Now you need to create `/etc/wpa.conf`

```
sudo nano /etc/wpa.conf
```

And add the following. Replace the `ssid` and `psk` as required

```
network={
 ssid="Your SSID Name"
 proto=RSN
 key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
 pairwise=CCMP TKIP
 group=CCMP TKIP
 psk="your-pass-key"
}
```

Then Reboot

Comment: Thanks for response, maybe a stupid question but my SSID has `"` in it. Can I just type `ssid=""SSIDname""`or does this work too `ssid='"SSIDname"'` or is there an other notation for `"`

Comment: Are you sure? That seems odd to have quotes in the name. Nevertheless, I would try just `ssid="SSIDname"` and `ssid="  \"SSIDname"\ "`. I am not 100% if using " \ "works. Remove the spaces. I had to add them in the comment so SE doesnt escape them :)